# Vectorizing distance to several points on Octave (Matlab)

Tags: vectorization, octave

I'm writing a `k-means` algorithm. At each step, I want to compute the `distance` of my `n` points to `k centroids`, without a for loop, and for `d` dimensions.

The problem is I have a hard time splitting on my number of dimensions with the Matlab functions I know. Here is my current code, with `x` being my `n 2D-points` and `y` my `k centroids` (also 2D-points of course), and with the points distributed along dimension 1, and the spatial coordinates along the dimension 2:

```
  dist = @(a,b) (a - b).^2;

  dx = bsxfun(dist, x(:,1), y(:,1)'); % x is (n,1) and y is (1,k)
  dy = bsxfun(dist, x(:,2), y(:,2)'); % so the result is (n,k)
  
  dists = dx + dy; % contains the square distance of each points to the k centroids
  [_,l] = min(dists, [], 2); % we then argmin on the 2nd dimension
```

How to vectorize furthermore ?

## First edit 3 days later, searching on my own

Since asking this question I made progress on my own towards vectorizing this piece of code.
The code above runs in approximately `0.7 ms` on my example.

I first used `repmat` to make it easy to do broadcasting:

```
dists = permute(permute(repmat(x,1,1,k), [3,2,1]) - y, [3,2,1]).^2;
dists = sum(dists, 2);
[~,l] = min(dists, [], 3);
```

As expected it is slightly slower since we replicate the matrix, it runs at `0.85 ms`.

From this example it was pretty easy to use `bsxfun` for the whole thing, but it turned out to be extremely slow, running in `150 ms` so more than `150 times slower` than the `repmat` version:

```
dist = @(a, b) (a - b).^2;
dists = permute(bsxfun(dist, permute(x, [3, 2, 1]), y), [3, 2, 1]);
dists = sum(dists, 2);
[~,l] = min(dists, [], 3);
```

Why is it so slow ? Isn't vectorizing always an improvement on speed, since it uses vector instructions on the CPU ? I mean of course simple for loops could be optimized to use it aswell, but how can vectorizing make the code slower ? Did I do it wrong ?

## Using a for loop

For the sake of completeness, here's the for loop version of my code, surprisingly the fastest running in `0.4 ms`, not sure why..

```
for i=1:k
  dists(:,i) = sum((x - y(i,:)).^2, 2);
endfor
[~,l] = min(dists, [], 2);
```

Comment: There is no real reason to avoid loops, if speed is what you want.

Comment: Well I heard matlab was optimized for computing on vectors and for loops weren't optimized well, atleast on older versions, isn't that true ?
Also this is about curiosity, I like fast algorithms but that's not my motive here.

Comment: Yeah, older, but quite older. As in, at least 5 or 6 years old. Current versions of MATLAB are pretty fast at loops. In any case, always write first the trivial solution, and make it more efficient later.

Comment: I'm already at the step of making is more efficent.
Also I'm not being paid for this so this will be learning and elegant coding first on this project.

Comment: You mean, you measured it and it was inefficient?  Have you bench-marked solutions then?

Comment: Bsxfun only hide the for loop, it does not vectorize your code. Use broadcasting instead of bsxfun.

Comment: @obchardon however, for many cases, bsxfun is *faster* than broadcasting. Because loops are often the fastest way....

Comment: @AnderBiguri is it also the case for Octave ?

Comment: @obchardon not sure actually. But leaving the comment up, as this is still tagged MATLAB, and its definitely true for MATLAB.

Comment: @Harkan Please don't tag MATLAB if you don't want MATLAB-specific answers. As it says in the tag descriptions, "Don’t use both the [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave] tags, unless the question is explicitly about the similarities or differences between the two."

Comment: @beaker Sorry for that, I just thought the vectorized code I was asking for would be the same in Matlab and Octave and had more chances of a faster answer by tagging with both, my bad ! Also the question is still open if you know how to vectorize my code above

Comment: @obchardon according to the doc bsxfun [does broadcast](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Broadcasting.html). Also can you elaborate please ? How can loops often be the fastest way while broadcasting allows for natural use of the CPU vector instructions to run the code in less cycles ?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have not bench-marked anything, forget about speed, I'm doing this for EDUCATIONAL purpose because array programming seems to my understanding to be the best way to have your code naturally optimized and also a concise and elegant way to write code.
By the way the questions is still open, I still don't know how to vectorize the code above.

Comment: Thats OK, we just disagree. A for loop is almost the simplest construct that I can imagine, it even fits our natural language "for each A in this array do X". I think they are clearer, concise, elegant and the best way to write code, unless there is an issue with them. You brought up optimization as an issue and I said that is not an issue. Simply pointing that out. I won't spend the time trying to do this because I don't see the point, thats all. Its good you are trying to learn different ways though, no objection.

Comment: For loops in a lot of cases are clearer, I agree with you on that. But they're not concise (several lines, indexing variable to go through your array) while the array programming approach can be closer to the mathematical definition, and give one-liners (probably why it can indeed not be clearer). For the same reasons I find it more elegant. And when you think about it, it gives more information to the compiler as to how to make your computation and about which part of your arrays depend to one another. I guess it can make your code easy to do lazy evaluation on, parallelize, etc.

Comment: @Harkan I would just use `dists = sum((permute(a, [1,3,2]) - permute(b, [3,1,2])).^2, 3);` I think you're forgetting that Octave (and now MATLAB) has implicit expansion.

Comment: Wow, you're right ! I did use implicit expansion in my repmat example so I know it's there, but I'm just very new to these dimension permutation tricks. Your solution is indeed very neat, you can add it as an answer below, I'll time your example and compare it with the others when I have the time for it in the next few days.

Answer (score 4):

Note: This answer was written when the question was also tagged MATLAB. Links to Octave documentation added after the MATLAB tag was removed.

---

You can use the `pdist2`<sup>[MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)/[Octave](https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/pdist2.html)</sup> function to calculate pairwise distances between two sets of observations.
This way, you offload the bother of vectorization to the people who wrote MATLAB/Octave (and they have done a pretty good job of it)

```
X = rand(10,3);
Y = rand(5,3);

D = pdist2(X, Y);
```

`D` is now a `10x5` matrix where the `i, j`th element is the distance between the `i`th X and `j`th Y point.

You can pass it the kind of distance you want as the third argument -- e.g. `'euclidean'`, `'minkowski'`, etc, or you could pass a function handle to your custom function like so:

```
dist = @(a,b) (a - b).^2;
D = pdist2(X, Y, dist);
```

As [saastn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2093077/saastn) mentions, `pdist2(..., 'smallest', k)` makes things easier in k-means. This returns just the smallest k values from each column of `pdist2`'s result. Octave doesn't have this functionality, but it's easily replicated using `sort()`<sup>[MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)/[Octave](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/sort.html)</sup>.

```
D_smallest = sort(D);
D_smallest = D_smallest(1:k, :);
```

Comment: Thanks that's pretty useful, even though still not answering my question :)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `pdist2(..., 'smallest', 1)` makes things easier in k-means.

Comment: @Harkan Not sure I understand. What part of the question did I miss answering?

Comment: The `pdist2` function of the `statistics` package of GNU Octave doesn't seem to implement that.

Comment: @Harkan That can be easily achieved using `sort`. See my edited answer.

Comment: How can you calculate the new center of mass of each centroid If you only consider the 'k' nearest points ? 'k' should be the number of centroids not the number of nearest feature, have I missed something here ?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi well I'm actually trying to vectorize it for educational purpose, because I've pretty much only done imperative programming so far and want to learn this way of processing data. Hence why this is not at all what I'm looking for, but I'm glad to know there exists such a function and I thank you for that.

Comment: @obchardon you haven't missed anything, the computation of the new center of mass comes AFTER this step, here we're trying to find the closest centroid to each one of our points, hence why k = 1 and has nothing to do with the number of centroids k I used in my definitions.

Comment: @Harkan no worries! I'll try to edit the answer to include vectorization from scratch in a few days.